# Telerik RadNumUpDown horizontal content

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I'm using a telerik radnumupdown control.  I'm trying to get the content of the control to be left justified.  My code is below:

```
<telerik:RadNumericUpDown HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"  SmallChange="1" NumberDecimalDigits="0" ValueFormat="Numeric" IsEditable="True" Value="{Binding Value}"/>
```

The content is left justified, however, there seems to be some padding to the left of the entered integers.

[image]

This is a problem because I'm using a radmaskedtextbox control right above this control for decimal values and the alignment is different for both.

Answer (score 0):

I've put a RadMaskedTextInput next to a RadNumericUpDown and the left margin seems to be the same: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxPj1.jpg

I'm using telerik's Window7 theme. Am I missing something?